# Может ли Qt5 взаимодействовать с X11?

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, графика, x11

Стоит задача написать свою графическую оболочку наподобие GNOME, KDE, XFCE. Язык исполнения С++, фреймворк Qt5. Насколько я понимаю нужно заставить Qt5 взаимодействовать с X11 для отрисовки графики. Подскажите Qt5 обладает такими возможностями или эту задачу нужно решать другими путями? Спасибо

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что этот вопрос имеет практическую ценность. Qt предназначен в первую очередь для написания GUI приложений. Нет смысла в одиночку писать новое графическое окружение.

Comment: Для меня имеет смысл. Иначе не спрашивал бы

Comment: @mymedia, KDE написан с использованием Qt. Это возможно сделать.

Comment: На этом сайте можно задавать вопросы, которые имеют отношение _"к **реальной** проблеме, встречающейся **на практике**, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев"_. См. [help/on-topic]. Я не уверен, что вопрос будет полезен кому-нибудь ещё из дальнейших посетителей. Потому что обычно не встаёт задачи именно написать своё собственное окружение, а зачастую пытаются подстроить под себя уже существующие решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цитата:

> Так же как и в случае ОС Windows, в ОС UNIX библиотека Qt
>   предоставляет возможность доступа к событиям на низком уровне. Класс
>   QWidget содержит метод x11Event(), который необходим для получения
>   событий оконной системы X Window. Чтобы получать события, этот метод
>   нужно переопределить. Если после завершения метода не требуется
>   продолжать обработку события методами Qt, то из этого метода нужно
>   вернуть значение true.

Макс Шлее. "Qt 4.8. Профессиональное программирование на C++"